Is there a way to run a file that is in a directory with a special character in the name?
My directory structure is C:\Users\...\[MATH] foldername
So to change directories, as per some SE post I saw, I have to use:
cd 'C:\Users\...\`[MATH`] foldername'
which indeed changes to the required directory.
Once here, I use py -m venv Project, and it creates the Project folder with the venv stuff correctly.
When I try to run Scripts\activate,
I get the following error:
Line |

185 | $VenvDir = $VenvExecDir.Parent.FullName.TrimEnd("\\/")

| ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

| You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

Line |

138 | $pyvenvConfigPath = Join-Path -Resolve -Path $ConfigDir -ChildPat …

| ~~~~~~~~~~

| Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string.

Line |

206 | … ose " Got leaf-name of $VenvDir='$(Split-Path -Path $venvDir -Leaf)' …

| ~~~~~~~~

| Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string.Line |

207 | $Prompt = Split-Path -Path $venvDir -Leaf

| ~~~~~~~~

| Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string.

I don't really know how to proceed. Thanks in advance for help. If it helps I'm on a windows system.
Basically, I was able to narrow down the problem to the fact that my directory has a special character in it. Using the same procedure for other paths that don't have this causes no issues.

Python's bundled venv module (v3.4+), as of v3.12.3, has a bug that prevents it from working properly in directories whose names contain [ / ] in PowerShell.
These characters are metacharacters (characters with special meaning) in PowerShell wildcard expressions,
and arguments passed to the -Path parameter (which is also the first positional parameter) of file system-related cmdlets such as Get-Item and Get-ChildItem are interpreted as wildcard expressions.
To ensure verbatim interpretation of a path, use the -LiteralPath parameter instead.
You have two workaround options:

Bypass the problem by avoiding [ / ] in your project directory names.

Manually fix ./Scripts/bin/Activate.ps1 once your project has been initialized with python -m venv ./Scripts.

To do so, replace the line
$VenvExecDir = Get-Item -Path $VenvExecPath with
$VenvExecDir = Get-Item -LiteralPath $VenvExecPath



